# Is CCSlider is defined in coco2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have to make slider. Is coco2d contains CCSlider class? If not what is the easiest way to make CCSlider?

Answer (score 0):

CCSlider didn't support in original cocos2d library. However, it's a part of [cocos2d iPhone extension](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1506).

You can get CCSlider from

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/develop/Extensions/CCSlider